# How to retrieve a list of contacts that belong to a specific group or label from Google People API

Tags: php, google-api, google-people-api

I'm trying to get a list of contacts that are in the same group by using Google People API.

I can get a list of all contacts using people/me/connections and I can get a list of all groups using contactGroups, but I cant find anywhere that tells me how to get a specific list of contacts belonging to a specific group using the resourceName of the contact group

Answer (score 0):

You know how you can look for ages and then as soon as you ask for help, you find your answer? 
Use people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=contactGroups/*}
returns the resourceName of each contact within the group
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get